# How to combine two variables directly in batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing simple batch file as post-build action in Visual Studio and I cannot get rid of quotes which are added when I am combining two variables. The code looks like this:

```
set SolutionDir=%1
set ConfigurationName=%2

set AltSourceDir=%SolutionDir%\%ConfigurationName%

echo "%AltSourceDir%"
```

In the point of merge I get quotation marks:

```
""D:\WORK\Extractor\"\"Release""
```

How to merge them directly?

Comment: How do you provide the parameters when you call the batch file?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, as `"$(SolutionDir)" "$(ConfigurationName)"` -- this part is intended, otherwise I would get splits on whitespaces (if present).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%~1` removes quotes. See `call /?`.